# Can't access Google Drive from Google Apps Script without a paid account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I can't seem to be able to access my Google Drive using the Google Apps Script Drive services.
This: `DriveApp.getFolderById('1Evf...Kein')` is not returning any value, just null.

For example, this function from my library that used to work may times - returns nothing now on the call to DriveApp:

```
function getFileByNameInFolder(folderID, fileName) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  
  console.log(folder);
  console.log(files);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    console.log(file.getName());
   var file = files.next();
    if (file.getName() == fileName) {
     return file; 
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Result in console.lor:

[image]

**Any use of the DriveApp service is blocked.**

I tried from a standalone Apps Script and from a Sheet-bound Apps Script - not working.

I am sure it worked in the past for my past projects!

Reading around, is it possible that Google blocked the use of these services unless you are on some paid account with them (Google Workspaces or Google Cloud)?

Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Google has not blocked the use of apps script in my free accounts

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: You're missing something else. Please share your code.

Comment: Cooper. Only certain services are blocked - not GAP overall. DriveApp is not working anymore. Correct?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or sample execution logs? I tried it on my gmail account and it is working from my side

Comment: Thanks Ron. Added screenshot. The issue is the returned {} (the followig error is just because nothing was returned previously).

Answer (score 0):

Your DriveApp service did not stop working. Based on your code,
It is expected that  `console.log(folder);`and `console.log(files);` will display `{}` in the execution logs since you did not use [console.log(formatOrObject, values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#logformatorobject,-values) to log Apps Script object successfully in the execution log.

`{}` displayed using console `console.log(folder);` doesn't mean that DriveApp service is not working. You can verify that by replacing it with `Logger.log(folder)`. The main issue why your code is failing is because you called `console.log(file.getName());` while `file` variable is not yet defined/initialized with the [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) object (return of `files.next()`).

It should be like this:

```
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    
    var file = files.next();
    console.log(file.getName());

    if (file.getName() == fileName) {
     return file; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ron. My issue is that DriveApp service stopped working.